# Xtext - Proposal Provider actual line

Tags: dsl, xtext

I for giving good proposals in Xtext I need to know the text entered before the actual proposal.

With eAllContents I can see all the text entered. Also the text after the actual line.

Is it possible to find out in which line the user currently is?

Thanks

Comment: i am not sure why you need this. the contentassistcontext should give you access to the ast as well as to the node model. the latter should give you access to the text before as well

Comment: hmm I know the possibillity to get a part of the current line with context.prefix. But what I need is to find the complete text in this specific line. Just the prefix is not enough. Thanks

Comment: as i said. you get nodes and can use there to access the text